# required version of pydot missing when trying to install pinterest/pinball

Tags: python, pip, pydot

I am trying to install [pinball](https://github.com/pinterest/pinball) via pip but I get stuck when it tried to install a dependency "pydot". The version required by pinball is 1.0.28 as is mentioned [here in the source](https://github.com/pinterest/pinball/blob/master/setup.py#L61).

The error I am getting is:

```
Collecting pydot==1.0.28 (from pinball)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pydot==1.0.28 (from pinball) (from versions: 1.0.2)
No matching distribution found for pydot==1.0.28 (from pinball)
```

I am new to the python/pip ecosystem and might be making a stupid/noob mistake. I have tried this on a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 (python version 2.7.9, pip installed via apt) and Mac OSX El Capitan (python version 2.7.10, pip installed via homebrew). Same error in both cases.

I am using virtualenv. I have graphviz and mysql installed successfully.

**EDIT**

Found one [closed issue](https://github.com/pinterest/pinball/issues/9) that says the same thing.

Comment: i tried installing pydot on os x a while a go and gave up ... it does work on linux, maybe consider running a VM?

Comment: I found one closed issue that ...well...it doesn't really solve the problem per say...but...[take a look](https://github.com/pinterest/pinball/issues/9)

Comment: uhi yeah i don't know, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This rather manual procedure worked in Linux (debian jessie)

First, retrieve and unpack the software

```
pip install --download /tmp https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/archive/pydot-1.0.28.tar.gz
cd /tmp
tar xf pydot-1.0.28.tar.gz
cd pydot-pydot-1.0.28
```

Then edit *pydot.py*, change

```
__version__ = '1.0.%d' % int( __revision__[21:-2] )
```

to

```
__version__ = '1.0.28'
```

After editing

```
pip install --upgrade .
pip install --upgrade pinball
```

Comment: Damn...I don't understand half of what we're changing here. Btw. I solved it by just downloading the source and manually building it in the `env`. Thanks :)